# Sega 32x passthrough works but 32 bit cards don't

Tags: sega-genesis, sega-32x

I have a Sega 32x that I bought off ebay as not working.
I have tried it in a Megadrive Genesis, with and without MegaCD and also in a Megadrive II with and without MegaCD.
Passthrough (with Genesis games) works fine.
I have three 32x Carts (Starwards, Virtua Racing and Doom) and none of these work.
The Sega copyright screen appears but then nothing.

I have cleaned and tested continuity on all the connectors and also on the white ribbon cables.
Everything seems fine.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so it appears to be related to cleanliness of the contacts. I cleaned them with contact cleaner but I think this has some detergent in it - I've now cleaned them with IPA and it's working fine.